# Сокращенный адрес с яндекс карт

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Есть задача: выводить сокращенный адрес. Т.е. не "улица Вишневского", а "ул.Вишневского". Поискав в яндекс API ничего подобного там нет. Может кто знает как выводить сокращенно не костылями? Мб невнимательно изучила API?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Это уже не на уровне АПИ яндекса должно делаться а на уровне вашей программы. Метод repalce в помощь, костылем это не будет считаться.

Comment: Соглашусь. Задача геокодера (или JS API, ППО) - дать почтовый адрес. Иногда с множеством дополнительных структур и полей. А вот сокращение названий типов топонимов - персональная хотелка. Какой вид сокращения и на каком этапе делать - действительно repalce.

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили!